# Vue3.0 version + typescript + quasar-app-extension yarn build error

Tags: vue.js, build, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm using Vue3.0 version + typescript + quasar-app-extension

What I did

`yarn build` which in turn runs `node build/index.js`. But I encounter an error
I don't know why I'm getting an error
Keep in mind that this is example code from a ui kit for deployment to npm.

this is my example Vue code

```
<template>
  <div>
    <QBadge :label="title" class="MyComponent" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, PropType } from 'vue';
import { QBadge } from 'quasar';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyComponent',
  components: { QBadge },
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String as PropType<'hello'>,
      default: () => 'hello',
    },
  },
  setup() {
    return {};
  },
});
</script>
```

this is my error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (3:18)
    at pp$4.raise (C:\Users\eunjin\Documents\workspace\quasar-ui\ui\node_modules\buble\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2825:15)
    at pp.unexpected (C:\Users\eunjin\Documents\workspace\quasar-ui\ui\node_modules\buble\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:689:10)
    at _class.jsx_parseIdentifier (C:\Users\eunjin\Documents\workspace\quasar-ui\ui\node_modules\acorn-jsx\index.js:257:14)
    at _class.jsx_parseNamespacedName (C:\Users\eunjin\Documents\workspace\quasar-ui\ui\node_modules\acorn-jsx\index.js:266:23)
    at _class.jsx_parseAttribute (C:\Users\eunjin\Documents\workspace\quasar-ui\ui\node_modules\acorn-jsx\index.js:343:24)
    at _class.jsx_parseOpeningElementAt (C:\Users\eunjin\Documents\workspace\quasar-ui\ui\node_modules\acorn-jsx\index.js:356:35)
    at _class.jsx_parseElementAt (C:\Users\eunjin\Documents\workspace\quasar-ui\ui\node_modules\acorn-jsx\index.js:378:33)
    at _class.jsx_parseElementAt (C:\Users\eunjin\Documents\workspace\quasar-ui\ui\node_modules\acorn-jsx\index.js:391:32)
    at _class.jsx_parseElementAt (C:\Users\eunjin\Documents\workspace\quasar-ui\ui\node_modules\acorn-jsx\index.js:391:32)
    at _class.jsx_parseElement (C:\Users\eunjin\Documents\workspace\quasar-ui\ui\node_modules\acorn-jsx\index.js:436:19) {
  pos: 37,
  loc: Position {
    line: 3,
    column: 18,
    file: 'C:\\Users\\eunjin\\Documents\\workspace\\quasar-ui\\ui\\src\\components\\Component.vue'
  },
  raisedAt: 38,
  snippet: '1 : <template>\n' +
    '2 :   <div>\n' +
    '3 :     <QBadge :label="title" class="MyComponent" />\n' +
    '                      ^',
  toString: [Function (anonymous)],
  plugin: 'buble',
  frame: '1 : <template>\n' +
    '2 :   <div>\n' +
    '3 :     <QBadge :label="title" class="MyComponent" />\n' +
    '                      ^',
  code: 'PLUGIN_ERROR',
  hook: 'transform',
  id: 'C:\\Users\\eunjin\\Documents\\workspace\\quasar-ui\\ui\\src\\components\\Component.vue',
  watchFiles: [
    'C:\\Users\\eunjin\\Documents\\workspace\\quasar-ui\\ui\\src\\index.common.js',
    'C:\\Users\\eunjin\\Documents\\workspace\\quasar-ui\\ui\\src\\vue-plugin.js',
    'C:\\Users\\eunjin\\Documents\\workspace\\quasar-ui\\ui\\src\\components\\Component.vue'
  ]
}
[css]  dist\index.css                              0.15kb (gzipped:   0.15kb)
[css]  dist\index.rtl.css                          0.15kb (gzipped:   0.15kb)
[css]  dist\index.min.css                          0.14kb (gzipped:   0.14kb)
[css]  dist\index.rtl.min.css                      0.14kb (gzipped:   0.14kb)
Done in 2.26s.
```

Please help me out~!

Comment: did you try `:label="this.title"`? To access props you need to use the `this` keyword

Comment: @ca1c this is Vue3.0, You are speaking Vue 2 syntax.

Comment: Even in Vue 2, you did not have to use `this` in the template for anything.  Anyways, every line of the stacktrace mentions the acorn-jsx module.  As far as I can tell it's not a Quasar related package.  Is this something you've installed?  You say this is example code, but where exactly is it from?

Comment: @yoduh I didn't install this package, it was installed automatically when I created the quasar app extension with `yarn create`.

Comment: @yoduh My guess is that "@rollup/plugin-buble": "^0.21.3", which seems to be in there. This is not what I installed.